# Cumulative Difference

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

```
Meter_Reading

MeterID    |    Reading     |     DateRead     |
1               10                1-Jan-2012
1               20                2-Feb-2012
1               30                1-Mar-2012
1               60                2-Apr-2012
1               80                1-May-2012
```

The reading is a cumulative value where i would need to calculate the difference from the previous month and the current month.

Could you help me figure out how to generate a view where i can see the consumption (previous month reading - current month reading) for each month?

I had tried the between function:

```
select address, reading as Consumption, dateread
from ServiceAddress, reading, meter
where address like '53 Drip Drive%'
and dateread 
between (to_date('01-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')) and (to_date('30-SEP-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
and serviceaddress.serviceaddid = meter.serviceaddid and meter.meterid = reading.meterid;
```

but all i got was the readings for each month not the difference.

How could I make it list the monthly consumption?

Comment: What happens if a month is missing?

Comment: i guess it will just skip it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LAG` function to get the reading for the prior month.  The query you posted references three tables-- `ServiceAddress`, `Reading`, and `Meter` none of which are the `Meter_Reading` table you posted the structure and data for.  I'll ignore the query you posted since I'm not sure what the data in those tables looks like and focus on the `Meter_Reading` table that you posted data for

```
SELECT MeterID, 
       DateRead,
       Reading,
       PriorReading,
       Reading - PriorReading AmountUsed
  FROM (SELECT MeterID,
               DateRead,
               Reading,
               nvl(lag(Reading) over (partition by MeterID 
                                          order by DateRead), 
                   0) PriorReading
          FROM meter_reading)
```

I assume that if there is no prior reading that you want to assume that the prior reading was 0

Comment: yes i am sorry i did not explain the other table structures, i believe it would not be necessary for this query. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Justin, could i just confirm the "PriorReading PriorReading," line has no purpose right? I could simply put "PriorReading,". From what i executed it seems possible.

Comment: @ChrisPin - The alias has no point, yes.  I was originally applying the `NVL` in the outer query rather than in the inner query so the alias was originally there for that.  I updated my answer to eliminate the redundant alias

Comment: @JustinCave `lag(Reading, 1, 0) over()` will return zero when first row is being processed. Why to call `Nvl` function?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - The `NVL` is not necessary if you specify an explicit default (the third argument) which requires that you specify an explicit number of rows to look back (the second argument).  It is necessary if you do a simple `lag(Reading)` like I did here.  Personally, I find the `NVL` approach easier to read but that's just because I don't always remember off the top of my head the order of the optional arguments to `lag`.

Answer (score 8):

Try with [analytic functions](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55). Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT meterid, dateread, 
    reading - LAG(reading, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY meterid ORDER BY dateread)
FROM meter_reading
```

Comment: thanks alot. wow. interestingly awesome. analytic function, thanks for the link :D