# Difference of cumulative data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having table which has following column In column "value" data get cumulative and data is fetch at 15 min time Interval

```
name  | value   | start_time          |end_time            |
------------------------------------------------------------
likes | 5       |2013-05-29 16:30:00  |2013-05-29 17:45:00 |
likes | 6       |2013-05-29 17:00:00  |2013-05-29 17:15:00 |
likes | 6       |2013-05-29 17:30:00  |2013-05-29 17:45:00 |
likes | 10      |2013-05-29 18:00:00  |2013-05-29 18:15:00 |
likes | 10      |2013-05-29 18:30:00  |2013-05-29 18:45:00 |
likes | 11      |2013-05-29 19:00:00  |2013-05-29 19:15:00 |
likes | 11      |2013-05-29 19:30:00  |2013-05-29 19:45:00 |
```

I want sql query which fetch data for every 1hour and data in "value" column should be actual data not cumulative

Eg :

```
name  | value   | start_time          |end_time            | 
------------------------------------------------------------
likes | 1       |2013-05-29 17:00:00  |2013-05-29 17:59:00 |
```

OR

```
name  | value   | start_time          |end_time            | 
------------------------------------------------------------
likes | 1       |2013-05-29 17:00:00  |2013-05-29 17:15:00 |
likes | 0       |2013-05-29 17:30:00  |2013-05-29 17:45:00 |
```

I want "value" column data as actual data for that period not cumulative data

Comment: What is your actual query?

Comment: show some table schema

Comment: In second column ie "value" data is getting added to previous data while showing result i want data to be subtracted from previous data in value column

Comment: How do you calculate the new value? That's not clear at all.

Comment: I want query which will display row6-row5 result in row6 for "value" column. similar row5-row4 into row5, row4-row3 into row3 some what like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460193/cumulative-difference   differences between pairs of successive rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table my_test ( `name` char(5), `value` int,  `start_time` datetime, `end_time` datetime);
```

I have corrected the first end time because I think it was a typo ( 2013-05-29 17:45:00 to 2013-05-29 17:00:00 ):

```
insert into my_test values
('likes', 5 ,      '2013-05-29 16:30:00',  '2013-05-29 17:00:00'),
('likes', 6 ,      '2013-05-29 17:00:00',  '2013-05-29 17:15:00'),
('likes', 6 ,      '2013-05-29 17:30:00',  '2013-05-29 17:45:00'),
('likes', 10,      '2013-05-29 18:00:00',  '2013-05-29 18:15:00'),
('likes', 10,      '2013-05-29 18:30:00',  '2013-05-29 18:45:00'),
('likes', 11,      '2013-05-29 19:00:00',  '2013-05-29 19:15:00'),
('likes', 11,      '2013-05-29 19:30:00',  '2013-05-29 19:45:00');
```

I have a quick query which I think kind of does the right thing but the time boundaries are bit off.

```
select 'likes' `name`, l2 - l1 `value`, `start`.`start_time` `start_time`,  `end`.`end_time` `end_time`   from
    (
        select date_format(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') start_time, max(value) l1 from my_test group by date_format(start_time, '%Y%m%d%H')
    ) as `start` join 
    (
        select date_format(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') end_time, max(value) l2 from my_test group by date_format(start_time, '%Y%m%d%H')
    ) as `end` on `start`.start_time + interval 1 hour = `end`.end_time;
```

Results in the following:

```
name  | value  | start_time          |end_time              |
------------------------------------------------------------- 
likes | 1      | 2013-05-29 16:00:00 |  2013-05-29 17:00:00 |
likes | 4      | 2013-05-29 17:00:00 |  2013-05-29 18:00:00 |
likes | 1      | 2013-05-29 18:00:00 |  2013-05-29 19:00:00 |
```

Comment: change the first line of the query to:
select 'likes' `name`, l2 - l1 `value`, `end`.`end_time` `start_time`,  date_format(`end`.`end_time`,'%Y%m%d %H:59:59') to get the expected boundaries.

Comment: where to add this line date_format(end.end_time,'%Y%m%d %H:59:59')